# Ender 3Pro Calibration problem

Tags: creality-ender-3, calibration

I have a new Ender 3 Pro.  I set it up and everything seems to work. I configured as such that the nozzle is only a sheet of paper apart from the bed. When I go to print, the extruder raises 2-3 mm and starts printing, which doesn't stick to the bed and all I get is a mess. Bed is set to 60 °C and hotend to 210 °C.

Comment: mind showing a photo and telling us what slicer you use?

Comment: Hi Howard, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! What is your start G-code? Or, put a link to PasteBin to your G-code file so we can help you. Unfortunately, your question does not have enough information to help you now. My best guess is that your start G-code is incorrect.